# What does 幸せになれると信じています mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, questions

I was thinking it meant "I believe I can be happy"

Answer (score 1):

If I just read it literaly, it does mean what you said at least. "幸せになれる" means "I can be happy" just like "と信じています" does mean that "You are believing" so it will means "I believe I can be happy in the future". I would like to put "in the future" because it does sound like th person really want to be happy on a larger side than just "I can be happy".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  On this Stack Exchange site, we like to have our answers be useful for more than just the person asking the question.  Would you mind expanding the answer teaching us how you reached this conclusion? (Break it down and explain your reasoning.)